# jquery is working after doing an action or refresh in sharepoint

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I have a code to add a date with attachment in sharepoint page. I put this script code in the edit item page. But it works until refreshing the page or until doing an action. for example if I click on edit item, it doesn't change to the new name, if I close the edit item page, and open it again it changes. I want it to change directly. How can I do that?
This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", 'SP.ClientContext', RenameAttachments);
    });
var attfiles;
function RenameAttachments() {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    attfiles = ctx.get_web().getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Lists/Test/Attachments/' + getUrlParameter('ID')).get_files();
    ctx.load(attfiles);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailed));
}
```

Comment: **Do not ask same question again**. Your previous question - [https://stackoverflow.com/q/50852732/5832518](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50852732/5832518)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [my jquery is working until refresh only in sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50852732/my-jquery-is-working-until-refresh-only-in-sharepoint)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an alert to check whether this caused by jQuery library load.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", 'SP.ClientContext', function (){                        
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();            
            alert('111');
        });        
    </script>
```